# Populate 100 images using an If loop

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

I'm currently populating 100 images using the following code, but I'm sure there's a more economical way of doing it with an If statement:

```
mapblock01.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"block.png"]; mapblock01.hidden = TRUE;
mapblock02.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"block.png"]; mapblock02.hidden = TRUE;
mapblock03.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"block.png"]; mapblock03.hidden = TRUE;
mapblock04.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"block.png"]; mapblock04.hidden = TRUE;
mapblock05.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"block.png"]; mapblock05.hidden = TRUE;

------>

mapblock99.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"block.png"]; mapblock99.hidden = TRUE;
mapblock100.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"block.png"]; mapblock100.hidden = TRUE;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: will you want to show all image at same time?

Comment: No, the images are part of a tile map (made up of tiles in a 10 x 10 grid) that get revealed one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for it, you can give tag for each UIImageView as 1,2,3..100 and set image as below:

```
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
      UIImageView *imageV = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
      imageV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"block.png"];
      imageV.hidden = TRUE;
}
```

}

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as there's no reference to the image name which should be 'mapblock???'. NSLog shows imageV to be null.

Comment: Did you add tag with each imageview at the time of imageview creation?

Comment: Not sure what you mean there, sorry!

Comment: Okay, got it I think. I've set the ImageView's using storyboard so I can set the tags there.